# Creating a Schedule using CalanderView, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, schedule, calendarview

In my app, I am looking to create a schedule page where users are able to select a date and they will see what events are on that day.

I have created a page where an admin user can post an event which is then stored on a Firebase database.

I am having problems reading the inputted date from the post event page to the database. I want the format to be in DD/MM/YY.

Below is the code, I have used for the post event page, can anyone please give me advice on how to read the selected date to the database correctly.

Thanks

```
    private void startPostEvent() {

    final String eventTitle = mEventTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String eventDesc = mEventDesc.getText().toString().trim();
    final String calendarView= String.valueOf(mCalendar.getDate());

    mProgressEvent.setMessage("Posting Notification...");
    mProgressEvent.show();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(eventTitle) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(eventDesc) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(calendarView)) {



                DatabaseReference newNote = mdatabaseEvent.push();
                newNote.child("Event_Title").setValue(eventTitle);
                newNote.child("Event_Description").setValue(eventDesc);
                newNote.child("Event_Date").setValue(calendarView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String mDate = sdf.format(new Date(mCalendar.getDate()));
```